# Is there an easy code example of an exponential time algorithm?

Tags: dynamic-programming, exponential

I mean I know of algorithms which talk about generating exponential possibilities and iterating through them. But can anyone give me a pseudo code where the code goes through all cases and finds the answer.

Comment: You want an example of exponential time complexity algorithm?   Tautology check.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. The simple algorithm used for calculating the Fibonacci series without dynamic programming is the best example.

```
int f(n)
{
if(f == 0 || f == 1)
    return 1;
return f(n-1)+f(n-2);
}
```

This code takes exponential time. The time for calculating `f(n)` is proportional to the `n+1`th Fibonacci number. You can check this [link](http://davechessgames.blogspot.in/2012/03/maths-fibonacci-series-multiplying.html) to know about the growth of Fibonacci series (Courtesy : David Leese's [blog](http://davechessgames.blogspot.in/)). If you look at the logarithmic graph of Fibonacci series, you can see that it has an exponential growth.

The solution is dynamic programming, of course. Store the Fibonacci series elements that we have calculated so far and store it as a look-up table.